# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, json

Seems like there are many questions that are similar to mine but the answers posted there dosen't seem to work for me. My program is supposed to simply just open up a new page that allows webview.
But when i try to open this page, errors show without many hints on where the problem lies.

```
public class DetailedEventActivity extends Activity {

    TextView name;
    TextView desc;
    TextView link;

    String pid;
    String myName;
    String myDesc;
    String myLink;
    Button eLink;


    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single profile url
    private static final String url_event_detials = "http://10.0.2.2:8888/week_6/get_all_event.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_EVENT = "event";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "eventID";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "eventName";
    private static final String TAG_DESC = "eventDescription";
    private static final String TAG_LINK = "link";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_event);

        // getting profile details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting profile id (pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);
        myName = i.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
        myDesc = i.getStringExtra(TAG_DESC);
        myLink = i.getStringExtra(TAG_LINK);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
        //link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputLink);

        name.setText(myName);
        desc.setText(myDesc);
        link.setText(myLink);

        eLink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eventLink);

        eLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                WebView webview = new WebView(DetailedEventActivity.this);
                setContentView(webview);
                WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
                webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                webview.loadUrl(myLink);
             }
        }); 



        // Getting complete profile details in background thread

    }
```

And the codes leads up to this other class.

```
public class ViewEventActivity extends ListActivity {

    String pid;
    String name;
    String desc;
    String link;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventList;

    // url to get all profile list
    private static String url_all_event = "http://10.0.2.2:8888/week_6/get_all_event.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_EVENT = "event";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "eventID";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "eventName";
    private static final String TAG_DESC = "eventDescription";
    private static final String TAG_LINK = "link";

    // profiles JSONArray
    JSONArray event = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_event);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        eventList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading profiles in Background Thread
        new LoadAllEvent().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();
        // on seleting single event
        // launching Edit event Screen

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
               // String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();

                //Roy
                String myPid = eventList.get(position).get(TAG_PID);
                String myName = eventList.get(position).get(TAG_NAME);
                String myDesc = eventList.get(position).get(TAG_DESC);
                String myLink = eventList.get(position).get(TAG_LINK);

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailedEventActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, myPid);
                Log.d("Put Extra ", "id = "+ myPid);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, myName);
                Log.d("Put Extra ", "name = "+ myName);
                in.putExtra(TAG_DESC, myDesc);
                Log.d("Put Extra ", "desc = "+ myDesc);
                in.putExtra(TAG_LINK, myLink);
                Log.d("Put Extra ", "link = "+ myLink);
                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
               startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        }); 

    }

    // Response from Edit profile Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted profile
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all profile by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllEvent extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewEventActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading event. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All profiles from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_event, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Event ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // profiles found
                    // Getting Array of profiles
                    event = json.getJSONArray(TAG_EVENT);

                    // looping through All profiles
                    for (int i = 0; i < event.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = event.getJSONObject(i);

                        Log.d("View Json ", "i = "+i);
                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        Log.d("View Json ", "id = "+ id);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        Log.d("View Json ", "name = "+ name);
                        String desc = c.getString(TAG_DESC);
                        Log.d("View Json ", "desc = "+ desc);
                        String link = c.getString(TAG_LINK);
                        Log.d("View Json ", "link = "+ link);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_DESC, desc);
                        map.put(TAG_LINK, link);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        eventList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no profiles found
                    // Launch Add New profile Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MainScreenActivity.class);
                    //Main Page Aagin
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewEventActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Redirecting to main page");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pDialog.show();
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all profiles
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            ViewEventActivity.this, eventList,
                            R.layout.list_event, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

And the error i keep getting on the LogCat is:

```
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.DetailedEventActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.example.test.DetailedEventActivity.onCreate(DetailedEventActivity.java:77)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-17 11:21:55.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     ... 11 more
```

I am aware that this question might seem trivial but i just started learning java last month, so guidiance and help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your textview link causes null pointer exception,

```
link.setText(myLink); // <-- null here
```

so change

```
//link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputLink);
```

to

```
link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputLink);
```

Comment: @TohJunRong Happy to help,enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the link object without a proper initialization:

```
  //link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputLink);
  link.setText(myLink);
```